# Is teletyping a function of modern computers?

Tags: computer-science

The internet tends to give a good description of teletyping when referring to "ancient" computer systems (basically, computers before PCs, lol) but im not sure of how they relate to computers we use today. I read somewhere that the BIOS uses teletyping, and when i go to background terminals in Ubuntu it lists the OS Name, computer name, then tty (which stands for "teletyping")

Could anyone give a complete-as-possible (or as complete as you want) description of the way teletyping is used in modern computers?

Comment: "I read somewhere that the BIOS uses teletyping" Where'd you read that? Can you provide a reference?

Comment: no i can't, sorry my memory is not a scientifically objective or legitamate resource, maybe in the happy utopian society computers will be stuck up everyones butthole so we don't have to think

Comment: Uhh ok....  Sorry I asked..

Comment: nah im sorry, i just don't really like the downvote, it doesn't really seem to help anything

Answer (score 3):

"[Teletype](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teletype_Model_33)" is brand name for a make of teleprinter (aka **T**ele**TY**pewriters), which are a [type of device](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teleprinter).

As for TTY's usage in Linux - here's a question over on Ask Ubuntu:

[What does “TTY” stand for?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/481906/what-does-tty-stand-for)

From the [accepted answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/481915):

> Early user terminals connected to computers were electromechanical teleprinters or teletypewriters (TeleTYpewriter, TTY), and *since then TTY has continued to be used as the name for the text-only console*.